# How to delete a data based on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i accomplished now is when i clicked "add to my stay" button, it will display the name and price data and it will automatically switch to remove button and then click again for another addon to display another name and price data. Now if i press the remove button of the 1st "add to my stay"  it will delete both data on each button that i pressed adding. My goal is to remove a data based on its button ID like i want to remove The data on my 1st "Add to my stay" button it will only delete the 1st data
MY JS CODE FOR REMOVE it is outside the (document).ready

```
function Remove(id) {
            console.log("call remove");

            $('li.price').each(function (index, object) {
                var id2 = $(object).data('addon-id');
                console.log(id);
                if (id2 === id2) {
                    $(object).remove();
                }
            });
            $(this).addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.addons[data-addon-id="' + id + '"]').removeClass('is-hidden');
        }
```

My code for getting the data on add to my stay button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addons").on("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();


        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $(this).data('addon-id');
        name = $(this).data('name');
        price = $(this).data('price');

        console.log(id);

        $(this).addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.removebtn[data-addon-id="' + id + '"]').removeClass('is-hidden');
        if(id != '')

            {

                    $.ajax(
                {
                    type:"POST",
                    url : "Pages/addonajax",
                    data:{id:id,
                        name:name,
                        price:price},


                    success:function(data)
                    {
                            console.dir(data);
                            if (data) {

                            var item = $('<li data-itemprice="'+price+'" class = "price">'+name+' : '+price+'</li>');
                                         $("#test1").append(item);
                               Total();

                        }
                        else {

                        } 
                    }
                });
      }      
});
```

My code on the button

```
<button data-name = "Airport Transfer" data-price = "4300"  class="addons addon-btn trans_200" data-addon-id ="1">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
<button class="removebtn remove-btn  is-hidden trans_200" data-addon-id ="1" onclick="Remove(1)" value="Remove">Remove</button>
```

Comment: why not just get the `li` like you get the addons? `$('li[data-addon-id="' + id + '"]').remove()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (id2 === id2) {
    $(object).remove();
}
```

`id2` will always be equal to itself, and therefore you will always call `$(object).remove();`

You need to compare `id2` to `id`

```
if (id2 === id) {
    $(object).remove();
}
```

**EDIT**

You also have a problem in your loop of the list items:

`var id2 = $(object).data('addon-id');`

Your list items do not have a `data-addon-id` attribute

Put a `data-addon-id` on the list item when you create it:

```
var item = $('<li data-addon-id="' + id + '" data-itemprice="'+price+'" class = "price">'+name+' : '+price+'</li>');
$("#test1").append(item);
```

Comment: i tried doing that but it says undefined in the console   undefined addons.js:133 here is the code console.log(id2);

Comment: @JedJamir What object is `"undefined"`?

Comment: var id2 = $(object).data('addon-id');

Comment: @JedJamir See my edit to my answer. Your list items do not have that data attribute, hence you get "undefined"